# How to use promise in vuex actions

Tags: vuejs2, vue-resource, vuex

Recently， i‘m trying to implement a RESTful api by using vuex and vue-resource. But when I use the vuex action to call the server api, I got the following problem.

My code in action looks like this:

```
import api from '../api/api.js'

const actions = {
getData (context, userId) {
  api.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .then((response) => console.log(response));//undefine
  }
}
```

My code in the api.js looks like this

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
get(url, request) {
     return Vue.http.get(url, request)
         .then((response) => {
           Promise.resolve(response.body);
           console.log(response.body);//ok
         })
         .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
    },
}
```

I the response of the api.js is fine. But the response of the action is undefined. It would be greatful if anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap an arrow function with curly brackets, you're now required to manually `return` something, which you are not doing.

Also, wrapping answers in `Promise.resolve` inside callbacks to `then` is pointless. Just return `response.body`.

Finally, `.catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));` is pointless. You end up with exactly the same thing you already have it you remove the whole `catch...` line of code entirely because you're just rejecting with the same error that you were already rejected with.

In other words, rework to:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

export default {
get(url, request) {
     return Vue.http.get(url, request)
         .then((response) => {
           return response.body;
         });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the action is that it should update data in the State via commits .. then you use the Store data in the Vue component .. actions should be void return ..

You should also be calling the action via a store.dispatch('getData', payload) sort of thing .. but since it returns a promise you can do an await of then() logic on the store.dispatch... (and in fact SHOULD do that)